# pasar fecha a dia semana JS

Tags: javascript

Empezando con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) me interesa pasar una fecha a dia de la semana en español. Después de ver y probar, termino haciendo lo siguiente pero no se automatiza ni aparece correctamente.

¿Pueden hecharme un cable?

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label col-sm-3">Fecha:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="date" id="fecha_ace2" name="fecha_ace2" class="form-control" tabindex="1" onchange="diaSemana()">
  </div>
  <script>
    function diaSemana() {
      var x = document.getElementById("fecha_ace2");
      let date = new Date(x.value.replace(/-+/g, '/'));
      let options = {
        weekday: 'long',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric'
      };
      console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('es-MX', options));
      $('#diaSemana').trigger('input')
    }
  </script>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="diaSemana" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Dia semana</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" id="diaSemana" class="form-control" value="" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te pasa es que no actualizas el valor del campo de texto en tu funcion "diaSemana()"

Aquí te dejo la corrección del código:

```
<script>
    function diaSemana() {
        var x = document.getElementById("fecha_ace2");
        let date = new Date(x.value.replace(/-+/g, '/'));

        let options = {
            weekday: 'long',
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'long',
            day: 'numeric'
        };
        let fechaFormateada = date.toLocaleDateString('es-MX', options);
        console.log(fechaFormateada);

        document.getElementById("diaSemana").value = fechaFormateada;
    }
</script>
```

con document.getElementById acedes al campo de texto por su id y con el .value acedes al valor del input.